# Bootstrap: Hide date picker after a date has been selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I use Bootstrap date picker. I want hide the date picker dialog box after a date has been selected by the user.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
var from_close = $(document).on('focus', ".date-picker", function() {
    $(this).datepicker();
});
 
$(document).datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    from_close.hide();
}).data('datepicker');
```

Comment: which is the plugin used

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$(".date-picker").on("changeDate", function () {
  $(this).datepicker("hide");
});
```

[Here are some examples](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker)

Comment: <!-- this for display dailog-->
$(document).on('focus',".date-picker", function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});
<!-- this is for hide dialog -->
 
$(".datepicker").on("changeDate", function () {
   $(this).datepicker("hide");
 });

I have try but now working, do you have any idea?

Comment: @user3382927, yup, depends on the case.

Comment: Sorry I write English in correct. My comment above is not working. please help me to solve it.

Comment: @user3382927 I have editted my answer. Use `$(".date-picker")` instead

Answer (score 0):

Use below option in date-picker function:

`{autoclose: true}`